# C++ memory issue with external library

Tags: c++, memory, alignment, memory-alignment

I worked for a commercial company, we have lots of internal libraries can be reused for different project. I just encountered serious memory issue with one of the library it is really strange.

The source code is confidential so I cannot put it here, I am going to mock up some code to describe what happened to me,

There are some classes defined in the library:

```
class ClassB
{
public:
   ...
   static ClassB* acquireInstance();
};
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassB* getB() { return m_pB; }
    bool init(ClassB* pB);
private:
    classB* m_pB;
};

we integrated this library(static linked) in our project, our code looks like this:

void Foo()
{
   ...
   ClassB* pB = ClassB::acquireInstance();
   ClassA a;
   a.init(pB); // I step into this function, the m_pB is properly assigned with pB, everything was OK inside this function.
   ASSERT(pB == a.getB()); // Failed
}
```

Comments:

The strange thing I found: when I step into the init function, the address of m_pB (&m_pB) is 0x0000ce08, but the address of m_pB (&a.m_pB) changed to 0x0000ce00.

I think it could be a byte alignment issue with different config between our project and the library. but I am not sure,

is there anyone encountered this kind of issue before, any idea about how to fix it ?

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: My guess is, you have two modules built with different definitions of `ClassA`. They don't agree on the binary layout of the object. Look for new member variables introduced recently, or existing members changed from a 32-bit to a 64-bit type, or something along these lines.

Comment: Are you mixing debug and release builds? Try matching builds.

Comment: @Sahu, No, I didn't mixed the debug and release build. I am sure of this. But Igor remind me something I forgot to check, there is some macro defined in the classA used to support default platform or features, I will check the macros to make sure we defined the same macros. thank you all :) I will post the updates with my investigation.

Comment: Hi guys, I have found the reason, it is caused by the different macro defines. thanks to Igor! thank Sahu as well :)